# How to measure the performance of my site's video streaming and playback?

Tags: amazon-s3, video-streaming, html5-video, amazon-cloudfront, video.js

I have developed a site that hosts user videos. I store the video files in AWS S3, I deliver them through AWS Cloudfront and I use video.js as the site's player with HTML5 as default and flash as fallback.

Generally the video streaming seems to work fine but in some cases I receive complaints from users for slow or choppy video playback. I want to create some tests to measure the performance of streaming in order to be able to distinguish user problems (e.g. slow connection at the user side) or with my service.

Are there any best practices or tools to collect video delivery metrics? I'm interested in open source solutions or something that I can implement myself because it's just a personal project, but I don't want to rediscover the wheel.

Comment: Are you using a HTTP streaming protocol or just pseudo-streaming (progressive download)?

Comment: I'm using progressive download and all the videos have the moov atom at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Testing progressive download implies checking the transmission bandwidth and its continuity. For example for a high transmission rate the initial client buffer will be filled faster and the playback will start sooner. However, losing that transmission capacity at some later time can cause re-buffering. The total transmission time of your file must be lower than the video duration.

To identify potential issues you can start with the [S3 bucket logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/ManagingBucketLogging.html) and the [CloudFront cache statistics and access logs](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/10/21/amazon-cloudfront-cache-statistics-reports-faster-access-logs/).

There's a load testing tool written in Java called [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/index.html). It cannot use JavaScript so it must be configured to request the files directly.

The disadvantage of using a load test tool in a single location is pretty evident. Different geographical areas and carriers have different characteristics and test results will be different.

There are online, non open-source tools that can load test from multiple locations but they are generally paid though some offer free trials.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to look at this.

> but in some cases I receive complaints from users for slow or choppy video playback.

If you're using an Adaptive HLS stream, *and* you're CloudFront, and the video is still choppy to some users, that's probably because of their own internet connection speeds.

In that case, you can encode your video in multiple resolutions (using just one AWS MediaConvert job, btw) - like 1080p, 720p, 360p, 240p, 144p etc.

And then Videojs has a stream switcher plugin that will 1) automatically start playing the highest possible resolution - and no higher - that's right for the viewer's connection and  2) give the user the option via a "Settings" (gear) icon in the control bar that they can use to switch resolutions manually.

That way, even those with really poor internet connections should be able to watch your video.

Of course, the other alternative is to use progressive download videos that the viewer can simply click play, then immediately click pause, and wait for the video to buffer, and then play it after it's fully downloaded.

Check out the [Videojs Resolution Switcher demo here](https://s3mediavault.com/demo/streaming-video-demo/).

-- Ravi Jayagopal